# Recording audio interrupted by notifications, calls and screen timeout

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am currently working on an Android project on which we have a audio recorder module.

I am using MediaRecorder and it's working as expected except in some annoying situations :

- When a notification sound is triggered by Android, the MediaRecorder stops
- When receiving a phone call and even if refusing the call, the MediaRecorder stops
- When the screen goes off

```
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder ();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource (MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat (MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile (mFileName3GP);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder (MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate (96000);
    mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate (48000);
    mRecorder.start ();
```

I obviously doesn't want the audio recording to still be running during a call but on other situations I'd like my app to still perform the recording normally.

I didn't find anything pointing towards a solution. However, I am thinking about wakelocks (for screen off) and AudioFocus (for notifications and incoming calls).

Any  advice ?

Thanks,
ant1

Answer (score 1):

If this logic is embedded into an `Acitivity` it will be subject to the regular lifecycle changes in Android. Even if you prevent some normal operations from happening, you are then preventing/disrupting some of the expected behavior of the device. Maybe that is what you want, but there is another way.

You could use a `Service` instead:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

This will run in the background, so will not be affected by normal life-cycle interruptions, but you can still communicate via `BroadcastReceivers` and `Intents`.

This requires a little extra work to handle all the communication between the two, and possibly some kind of notification for the user to pause/stop/restart recordings, or whatever makes sense in your case.

**Update:**

Found this article on the Android docs which imply that you should be trying to pause and start your recording along with the activity pausing and starting:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Maybe this can help too. One comment mentioned that the microphone stops input when you make/receive a call. Maybe there are built in limitations to what you are trying to do:

[Pause and Resume Audio recording in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743165/pause-and-resume-audio-recording-in-android)

Comment: That might be the right approach when screen going off but will helps the recording not being stopped by a notification or an incoming call ?

Comment: AFAIK it will not be affected by notifications or calls, but don't have enough direct experience to say for certain.

Comment: Obviously, pausing the recording any time the Activity pauses is not a solution to the stated problem, though there will be situations in which the *service* performing the audio operations will need to discontinue them and get out of the way.