# Pause function in Audio Recorder

Tags: android, audio-recording, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, aac

I want to implement pause and resume functionality to my Audio Recorder. I know I cant use MediaRecorder to do this.
So please give me the source code of a class which can join two AAC audio file.

Comment: MediaMuxer possibly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Pause and Resume Audio recording in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900792/how-to-pause-and-resume-audio-recording-in-android)

Comment: Using bytes API, What happens when you join the bytes of **Audio2.aac** to the end of **Audio1.aac**. The nature of AAC is that its broken into frames so to add more frames you can just add more bytes at the end (the bytes being other AAC frames)

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

MediaRecorder added pause functionality from API level 24. If your minSdkVersion is less than 24, you can use the code below. It is extracted from **[this page](https://github.com/rahulraj64/MusicEditor-Deprecated-/blob/master/src/com/example/myrecording/AudioRecord_Player.java)**. It generates a wave file in the given name after the recording is stopped.

```
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class RecordAudio extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
    private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE = 8000;
    private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
    private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

    private Button recordButton, stopButton, pauseButton, resumeButton;
    private EditText recordingName;
    private AudioRecord recorder = null;
    private int bufferSize = 0;
    private Thread recordingThread = null;
    private boolean isRecording = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_record_audio);

        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
        recordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record_button);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
        resumeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resume_button);
        recordingName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.recording_name);

        recordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startRecording(false);
            }
        });

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopRecording(false);
            }
        });

        resumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startRecording(true);
            }
        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopRecording(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void startRecording(final boolean b) {
        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);
        recorder.startRecording();
        isRecording = true;
        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                writeAudioDataToFile(b);
            }
        }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
        recordingThread.start();
    }

    private void writeAudioDataToFile(boolean b) {
        byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
        String filename = getTempFilename();
        FileOutputStream os = null;

        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(filename, b);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int read = 0;

        if (os != null) {
            while (isRecording) {
                read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

                if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {
                    try {
                        os.write(data);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getTempFilename() {
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath + "/recording_temp.raw");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    private void stopRecording(boolean b) {
        if (recorder != null) {
            isRecording = false;

            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();

            recorder = null;
            recordingThread = null;
        }

        if (b == true) {
            copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(), getFilename());
            deleteTempFile();
        }
    }

    private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename, String outFilename) {
        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        long totalAudioLen = 0;
        long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 44;
        long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE;
        int channels = 2;
        long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE * channels / 8;

        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename, true);
            totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size() + out.getChannel().size();
            totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 44;

            WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                    longSampleRate, channels, byteRate, outFilename);

            while (in.read(data) != -1) {
                out.write(data);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void WriteWaveFileHeader(
            FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
            long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,
            long byteRate, String outFileName) throws IOException {

        byte[] header = new byte[44];

        header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
        header[1] = 'I';
        header[2] = 'F';
        header[3] = 'F';
        header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
        header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[8] = 'W';
        header[9] = 'A';
        header[10] = 'V';
        header[11] = 'E';
        header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
        header[13] = 'm';
        header[14] = 't';
        header[15] = ' ';
        header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
        header[17] = 0;
        header[18] = 0;
        header[19] = 0;
        header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
        header[21] = 0;
        header[22] = (byte) channels;
        header[23] = 0;
        header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
        header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
        header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8);  // block align
        header[33] = 0;
        header[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
        header[35] = 0;
        header[36] = 'd';
        header[37] = 'a';
        header[38] = 't';
        header[39] = 'a';
        header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
        header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

        RandomAccessFile rFile = new RandomAccessFile(outFileName, "rw");
        rFile.seek(0);
        rFile.write(header, 0, 44);
        rFile.close();
    }

    private String getFilename() {
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath + "/record_" + recordingName.getText() + ".wav");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    private void deleteTempFile() {
        File file = new File(getTempFilename());
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: i think it is recording. but, audio is not working.